# Ext.ux.Exporter.Button not exporting excel with data using ExtJS

Tags: extjs, export-to-excel, extjs3

I am trying to export Ext.Grid in excel or .xls but for some reason it will not fetch the data in Mac. The file is exported in .xlt format in windows and would not open in MS Office excel. Though the exported file has all the data when exported in Ubuntu and opened with Libre.

I am using the Ext.ux.Exporter as provided in the [github](https://github.com/edspencer/Ext.ux.Exporter). The file is Exporter-all.js which does all the work. I am really confused where am I going wrong?

This is the code on the excel export button,

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    title: "Intersected Species Info",
    store: stor,
    width: 585,
    height: 260,
    stripeRows: true,
    tbar: [],
    columns: columns,
    listeners: {
        render: function (grid) {
            grid.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();
        }
    }
});

var exportCSV = new Ext.ux.Exporter.Button({
    component: grid,
    text: 'Download CSV'
});

grid.getTopToolbar().add(exportCSV);
```

And this is from where I am importing the js file,

`<script src="../exporter/Exporter-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Where am I not correct?

Comment: "it will not fetch the data in Mac". What does it mean? An empty file?  How many bytes the downloaded file is? What does it contains?

Answer (score 0):

That github repository you use is for ExtJS 3 if I'm not wrong. You can use this https://github.com/iwiznia/Ext.ux.Exporter instead.

Remember to replace Style.js inside excelFormatter folder, using [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel&p=773479&viewfull=1#post773479)

Sorry to throw a bunch of links but [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel) thread explains pretty well. You can also follow example [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel&p=658711&viewfull=1#post658711).

Comment: The question is tagged with extjs3, so edspencer repo is correct.